# include variable to a logger

Tags: python, logging

what is the best way to include a variable in a logs?

I know the comment below from "How to input variables in logger formatter?" works, but its not really what I'm looking for.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

FORMAT = '%(MYVAR)s %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

logger.warning("'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves", extra={'MYVAR': 'Jabberwocky'})
```

I just want something like

```
x = 80
logging.info("Number x is: ", x)
```

I just want the log to have "Number x is: 80".  I cant seem to make it work.  Do I need to set up a logging filter?

Comment: Why can't you just use `logging.info("Number x is: %d" % x)` ?

Comment: Your example is _almost_ right -- you need to put a `%s` in the log message as a placeholder for the variable.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the `logging` [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-variable-data)

Comment: try this:  logging.info("Number x is: %d", x)